# Format BigDecimal to string with scientific notation and viceversa

Tags: java, bigdecimal, factorial

I have a function called factorial which calculates factorial for a large number and returns in BidDecimal

```
BigDecimal temp_val1 = factorial(555);
```

the above gives 66140856092779467090983316712427699021235xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Now i have to format the BigDecimal value to string with scientific notation

```
NumberFormat sci_formate = new DecimalFormat("0.#####E0");
String temp_s1 = sci_formate.format(temp_val1);
```

the above gives 6.61409E1283

Now i need to convert the string temp_s1(6.61409E1283) back to BigDecimal which gives the value of temp_val1....???? How to do that....

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
BigDecimal temp_val1 = new BigDecimal("6.61409E1283");
```

to format use

```
BigDecimal.toEngineeringString()
```

Comment: BigDecimal temp_val1 = new BigDecimal("6.61409E1283"); gives 6.61409E+1283.
    BigDecimal.toEngineeringString() returns the string representation of the decimal, how to cast this string to bigdecimal??

Comment: You cannot case String to BigDecimal you can parse it, new BigDecimal("6.61409E1283") parses it

Comment: BigDecimal temp_val1 = factorial(555); gives 66140856092779467090983316712427699021235xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx. 

Now i will format using DecimalFormat to show in scientific notation.
NumberFormat sci_formate = new DecimalFormat("0.#####E0");String temp_s1 = sci_formate.format(temp_val1); which gives 6.61409E1283.

Now i need to convert this String(6.61409E1283) back to BigDecimal which gives same value as temp_val1......

Comment: @GiriDhar doing exactly that will result in loss of precision.